# How to get a pointer to a C# non-blittable ref struct

Tags: c#, .net-core, interop, unsafe

I'm trying to pass a pointer to "ref Struct" to some C++ code via pinvoke so that it can be passed back to C# via a delegate callback (and then converted back to a ref) so as to avoid the default marshaling that occurs because the struct is non-blittable (see my other question [How to to pass a C# delegate (callback) with a ref struct parameter to C++ using SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63760330/how-to-to-pass-a-c-sharp-delegate-callback-with-a-ref-struct-parameter-to-c))

I can get a pointer to a normal struct containing non-blittable fields by using Unsafe.AsPointer.  However this won't compile (CS0306) for a ref struct as shown in the code below:

```
public struct NormalStruct
{
    public int value;
    public string text;
}

public ref struct RefStruct
{
    public int value;
    public string text;
}

NormalStruct ns = new NormalStruct() { value = 42 };
RefStruct rs = new RefStruct() { value = 42 };

// This works   
void* nsPtr = Unsafe.AsPointer(ref ns);

// This won't compile with CS0306;
void* rsPtr = Unsafe.AsPointer(ref rs);
```

Is there someway to get a pointer to a ref struct - or to change the default marshaling for a type

Comment: Why do you need a ref struct? they have a bunch of compiler limitations to make sure they will never end up on the heap and are completely stack based. Are you just trying to avoid copies ?

Comment: The choice of the ref struct is not mine.   The System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader is implemented as a ref struct.   I want to pass a pointer to it down to C++.   The C++ would not actually use the pointer but pass the pointer back to callbacks in the C# (where it would be converted back to a ref struct) to enable C++ code to read from a .NET JsonReader.  See my other question for more detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63760330/how-to-to-pass-a-c-sharp-delegate-callback-with-a-ref-struct-parameter-to-c

Comment: I don't think this can be done easily or reliably, ref structs have to live on the stack, even if you could do this, there is no way to keep the pointer to it alive, you would have to holdup execution for the callback where its alive and in scope. There are several compiler issues here. as well as conceptual ones.

Comment: You might be better keeping a reference to the ReadOnlySequence which is passed in and init a new Utf8JsonReader  somehow. actually i doubt that will help either :/

Comment: There isn't a problem with keeping the pointer alive in this case because all the code that actually uses the pointer is below it on the call stack.  I had a solution that actually worked passing the ref down along with the class that implements the callback interface - however because the runtime insists on marshaling in and out of the ref by copying to/from a buffer it is a lot slower than it should be.   My work around for the moment is to use the Newtonsoft JsonReader which is just a normal class and so doesn't suffer from any of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for a bit, but for anyone who finds this later, I was able to get this to work using this.

```cs
public void Method(ref MyStruct refStruct)
{
    fixed (MyStruct* structPointer = &refStruct)
    {
        // do something with ref struct here
    }
}
```